# Reuse cached QuerySet to prevent querying the database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, caching

I am trying to reduce the number of database hits in a portion of my app as much as possible as they have quite a negative performance impact.

I do all sorts of filtering on a given player's set of matches using any `QuerySet` operation like `filter`, `exclude`, `Q` objects, etc...

```
player.game_set.filter(Q1)
player.game_set.filter(Q2)
player.game_set.exclude(Q3)
```

And everytime any of `QuerySet`s sets are being executed, the databse is being hit.

I wonder if I could do the following: just hit the database once, to get the superset of the player's games:

```
player.game_set.all()
```

And then filter that **cached** `QuerySet`, but still using `QuerySet` operations like `filter`, `exclude` and `Q` objects. These would act on the cached `player.game_set.all()` rather than hitting the base every time.

Can this be done?

Comment: No, methods like `.filter()` construct a new queryset, and a queryset needs to hit the database to get results. It will never attempt to do equivalent operations in memory based on cached results of a previous queryset.

Comment: If you find that your queries are slow, that's probably because you may not have the optimal indexes. Please post your models (along with their indexes)